# How to read quantified statements without variables and unquantified statements with variables? What does an existence predicate achieve?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I was looking up free logic on wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_logic

and reading it posed more questions than it explained.

The "explanation" paragraph lists three theorems of predicate logic, for example:

$\forall xA \Rightarrow \exists xA$

and its corresponding free logic version

$\forall xA \land E!t \rightarrow \exists xA$

I have a hard time understanding these statements as there are no variables in the scope of $\forall$ or $\exists$. I could read something like

$\forall xA(x) \rightarrow \exists xA(x)$

but that is not what is written.

Similarly,

$Fy \rightarrow (E!y \rightarrow \exists xFx)$

just does not make sense to me. I just cannot make sense of $Fy$ which I take to be equal to $f(y)$, so there appears to be some sloppiness in notation. However, $f(y)$ is still cryptic. I guess part of my problem is with free variables but I cannot for the life of me come up with a statement in mathematics that contains a free variable (don't shoot me, I am a noob).

Side question: What does the introduction of an existence predicate achieve? I thought that existence is to be expressed through a quantifier and this helped me to make sense of Quine's slogan "to be is to be the value of a variable". The whole wiki article is rather cryptic for a beginner, so where can one read an easy summary of the topics touched upon here?

Comment: The issue is that in standard FOL the universal quantifier inplis the existential one. But, someone says, what about an empty worls? The universal is vacuously true but if there is nothing the existential one will be false.

Comment: No issue with variables; the rule applies to a generic formula A, with o vithout free occurrence of x.

Comment: Re second formula, what is wring with capital F?

Comment: Having said that, with standard semantic for FOL you can verify thatk, with simple model checking, the formula $Fy \to \exists x Fx$ is valid.

Comment: The issue with Free Logic, see Wiki entry, is that in it we may have non-designating constants ( r in the example) like Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why not have Sherlock Holmes in domain though? It might be a domain full of fictional entities.Why follow Quine in saying that a domain implies existence? We quantify over numbers in mathematics but that does not make us all platonists. Again, I just cannot make sense of free variables. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try thinking about formulas with free variables as schematic formulas. They occur in mathematics in the middle of proofs: to prove that $\forall  x(\phi(x) \to \psi(x))$, we say, let $x$ be such that $\phi(x)$ and then do some inference to deduce $\psi(x)$. Throughout that inference process $x$ is a schematic variable representing some unspecified object that satisfies the assumption $\phi(x)$ and we expresses its properties as formulas with $x$ as a free variable.

Comment: By the way, you are right that the Wiki page you cite is a bit inconsistent in its notation: sometimes they just write $A$ for a formula which may have free variables and sometimes they write $A(x)$. You might like to raise a comment to that effect on the Wiki page.

Comment: Maybe a more useful intro is SEP's entry on [Free Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/).

Answer (score 1):

I have made several corrections in the Wikipedia article; apparently, there was a confusion about the translation from Karel Lambert's [dot notation of *Principia Mathematica*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/#UseDotsForPunc) in his paper *[Free Logic and the Concept of Existence](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-8/issue-1-2/Free-logic-and-the-concept-of-existence/10.1305/ndjfl/1093956251.full)* to the contemporary notation. Thus,

$\forall xA(x) \rightarrow \exists xA(x)$ is now changed to $\forall xA \rightarrow (E!t \rightarrow A(t/x))$

$E!$ is not a quantifier, though it may look like one at first sight. It can be taken as a primitive logical predicate whereby $E!t$ says of a singular term $t$ that it is in the inner (i.e., seeking existential import) domain of quantification. Alternatively, $E!t$ can be taken as an open formula defined as $\exists x(x=t)$.

It may be helpful to remark that, when possible, reading a formula in the subject-predicate form  may provide a quicker intuitive idea than the function-argument form will do. Hence, one can read $Fy$ as saying that 'some $y$ is $F$'. The formula $Fy \rightarrow (E!y \rightarrow \exists xFx)$ introduces an additional assumption of existence (*denotatum*), $E!y$, for the singular term $y$ of which $F$ is predicated.

Lambert's open access paper mentioned above conveys the basic ideas quite clearly. John Nolt's article [*Free Logic*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/) offers a broader sweep, but not much more demanding.